How to import excel file to Python?
import pandas as pd
file1 = (r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Аналитик данных\ПИТОН программы\таблица эксел для тестирования.xls")
df = pd.read_excel("file1") 
print(df)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled5.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel("file1") 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 93, in import_optional_dependency
    raise ImportError(msg) from None
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.


** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **
Press Enter to exit terminal

I'm triyng to import excel file to Python.
Whats the problem?

Did you try to install xlrd, as the error message suggests?

I use  online Python.https://www.online-python.com/. Is it possible to install it here or I need offline version?

How is online-python supposed to read your C drive?

Thx bro!
